# Multiple aggregations to groups with .apply

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a weighted average on data I group with `groupby`. Using `.apply` works well, but I would like to create multiple aggregates on the same group in a clean way.

This is how I group and calculate the data:

```
def wavg(group):
    price = group['Price']
    volume = group['Volume']
    return (volume * price).sum() / volume.sum()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.groupby('Category').apply(wavg).reset_index()
```

I would like to create more than one aggregated column. For example, **I would like one column with the sum of all volumes for that group**.

Ideally, I would like to chain .apply and create multiple aggreated columns, or call .agg() with functions **that can access the whole group** (like apply can).

I would also like to be able to name the columns directly, the way I did it now created a column named "0".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.Series` for return ouput from [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def wavg(group):
    price = group['Price']
    volume = group['Volume']
    out = (volume * price).sum() / volume.sum()
    return pd.Series({'wa': out, 'sum': volume.sum()})

df1 = df.groupby('Category').apply(wavg).reset_index()
print (df1)
```

Another idea with helper column:

```
df1 = (df.assign(wa = df['Price'] * df['Volume'])
         .groupby('Category')
         .agg(wa = ('wa','sum'), 
              sum= ('Volume', 'sum'))
         .assign(wa = lambda x: x['wa'] / x['sum'])
         .reset_index())
```